# Facebook - need publish_actions permissions, cannot submit app for approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I am building a demo application as an assignment for a job interview. The app is not intended to be used publicly - I just run it from my local machine. The concept is to pull the logged in user's recent posts into a web page, then be able to click each one to view and DELETE comments on those posts. I need publish_actions permissions to be able to use the DELETE method via the API. I can submit my app for approval in order to get publish_actions permissions, BUT the submission page is not allowing me to do so. (https://developers.facebook.com/apps//review-status/items-in-review/)

I get the following message:
"It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

...Which is incorrect, because I submitted a DELETE request via the api to get the publish_actions permissions error in the first place. It looks like this:
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.fbadacb74({"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}});

I need to be able to submit the app submission form but cannot do so until I make an API request. But my API requests are not registering with the app. Is there any way to clear this error and submit the app? Am I stuck in an endless loop of permissions hell?!

Answer (score 1):

You got an error message, but you did not make a successful POST with `publish_actions`. Btw, **you can only DELETE posts made by your App**, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post#deleting

About submitting your App: You only need to do that if you want to make your App public. All those extended permissions will work without review for anyone with a role in your App.

Btw, i saw that you are trying to use `read_stream` in the Facebook Developers group, so you would not be able to get through review anyway. Check out this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Review docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

> However, in order to help you craft your Facebook Login experience, **your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.**

and

> **People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access to extended permissions without going through review (e.g. publish_actions or manage_pages).** For example, if you use the Facebook Plugin for Wordpress to publish your blog posts to your Facebook Page or Profile, you do not need to submit for review so long as all your publishers are listed in your app's Roles tab.